# DBI_QUERY replacement in twiki for HTTP

Tags: http, plugins, dbi, stateless, twiki

I am currently replacing some functionality in a twiki page that has been pulling data from a DB using the DBI_QUERY feature and generating a table complete with hyperlinks on one of the table columns.  Is there a way to generate a similar table from a comma separated file pulled from an HTTP request that twiki makes when the page is loaded?  Alternatively, I can pull the data as JSON.

Thanks,

SetJmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: apparently not.

However, using an iframe one can implant a table if the GET is already pre-formatted appropriately.

Will look forward to better answers...